# How do I assign the result of curl to a systemd variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, systemd

I am using an Amazon Web Service server, and am trying to setup a systemd job that takes as an input the [AWS external IP retrieved by `curl`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#using-instance-addressing-common).

```
[Unit]
Description=My example with AWS external IP
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=EXTERNAL_IP=$(/usr/bin/curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)
ExecStart=/path/to/myexample $EXTERNAL_IP

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The verify tool `systemd-analyze verify myexample.service` indicates there is a problem with `curl` and the environment assignment.

`Invalid environment assignment, ignoring: EXTERNAL_IP=$(/usr/bin/curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)`

If I replace the `curl` result with a hard-coded IP string, my daemon starts. How can I use the `curl` result in my systemd job?

Comment: Aren't you actually trying to get the external IP address fed into your application? There has to be some better way to do that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes. I pass EXTERNAL_IP to myexample.

Comment: Can the program not fetch the IP itself? That's probably the easiest thing to do.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The program is a TURN server, which I have not written. Is this difficult in systemd? I am new to systemd and expected this would be straightforward to resolve. If I need to modify the TURN source, I may just live with the hard-coded value.

Comment: A TURN server can't figure out its own external IP address? Oh, what delicious irony!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(First, I presume you are using [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) or one of its predecessors.)

To begin with, systemd units are not shell scripts and aren't parsed by a shell. This is why you can't just call a command and use its output as an environment variable.

However, [you *can* call a shell](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#id-1.8) from `ExecStart=`, which might be the fastest way to get up and running.

```
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/local/bin/turnserver -X $(/usr/bin/curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)'
```

(In this configuration you should *not* daemonize turnserver with `-o`.)

You could also write a script, which you can call from `ExecStartPre=`, which fetches your metadata and then [alters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11245144/1068283) `turnserver.conf`, which would occur before the daemon is started.

Comment: I ended up using the script called from `ExecStartPre` to alter the `turnserver.conf` file.